# "Whatever/whatsoever book you like you can take it"?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, free-relative-clauses

What is the difference between "whatsoever" and "whatever"?

Which of them can be used in the following sentence:

> 1. **Whatever** book you like you can take it.
> 2. **Whatsoever** book you like you can take it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this confusion before and thought I knew the answer. But when I wanted to cite some references, I was surprised.

**Whatever** as a pronoun, adjective or determiner is defined as ([LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/whatever_1)):

> any or all of the things that are wanted, needed, or possible

and about 7 more definitions (available at the dictionary link I provided) that don't apply to the example given.

But...

**[Whatever as an adverb](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/whatever_2)**:

> used to emphasize a negative statement [= whatsoever]

And when you look up **[whatsoever](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/whatsoever)**:

> used to emphasize a negative statement [= whatever]:

MW gives similar explanations for [whatever](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whatever) and [whatsoever](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what%20so%20ever).

To answer your question directly: in your example you should definitely use *whatever*. The word *whatever* has many meanings and it may be used instead of *whatsoever*. But vice versa does not apply - in your example, you cannot use *whatsoever* because in this context *whatever* has another meaning. Since there is a group of books to choose from, you might use [whichever](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whichever) instead of *whatever* in this context.

> Whatever book you like, you can take it.
>
> Whichever book you like, you can take it.
>
> You can take whatever/whichever book you like.

Comment: Basically agree, although I would recommend leaving off the _"it"_ in thses two sentences: _"Whatever book you like, you can take **it.**  Whichever book you like, you can take **it."** -_

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence where "whatever" and "whatsoever" are interchangeable? I can't think of any.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem *This is just a stupid argument that has nothing whatever to do with your job.* (an example in LEDO, on the page linked to above) I think *whatsoever* is fine, too.

Comment: Another example from LDOCE: *She has shown no interest whatever in anything scientific* If you say that one like this: *She has shown no interest whatsoever in anything scientific* or *She has shown no interest in anything scientific whatsoever* it conveys the same meaning, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think I agree. It sounds wrong to me, and I wouldn't say it. (I would use whatsoever instead of whatever) Maybe it's a dialect/location thing?

Comment: That's a question for someone more knowledgeable than me, I'm afraid...